# Deriving recurrence relations from a paragraph

Tags: algorithm, runtime, recurrence

I've recently gotten back into learning about discrete math. I enrolled in a course at university and am having trouble getting the hang of things again, especially when it comes to deriving a recurrence relation from a word problem. I would love to have some tips on how to do so.

**For example** (I've changed numbers from the homework question so if this doesn't work out just let me know): if Jean divides an input of size *n* into three subsets each of size n/5 and combines them in *theta(n)* time, what is the runtime? I got 3T(n/5) + theta(n) as the recurrence relation and I have no idea what the runtime is, and I feel like those are both incorrect.

I found this site (https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html) to be helpful for breaking down a recurrence relation into a solid runtime, but I still don't get how to get the recurrence relation from the word problem in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Think of such problems as tree structure with nodes on each level.Each node will contain a number the size of problem that you are dealing at a particular time and at each level you will have some nodes. This number could be 1,2,.......upto maximum n nodes at each level.

Now start from top level. You will have 1 node and the value in it will be 'n'(because at starting point we will have 'n' elements to deal with).

Now coming down to second level. In the above question says divide the problem(elements) in three parts at any point of time, so number of nodes on level 2 will be 3. The value in each node will be 'n/5'(because question says size of each subset is number of elements which were present on parent node divide by 5).Tree will look like:-

```
         (n)
     |     |     |
    (n/5)(n/5) (n/5)
```

Now going further down to 3rd level, tree will look like

```
                             (n)                                 level(1)
           |                  |                 |
        (n/5)               (n/5)             (n/5)              level(2)
      |   |   |          |    |    |      |     |     |
  (n/25)(n/25)(n/25) (n/25)(n/25)(n/25) (n/25)(n/25)(n/25)       level(3)
```

you will go on till the last level which will contain only 1 element and total number of nodes will be 'n'.

So, if you need to write the recursion just see level 1 and level 2.

```
Time taken to solve problem with 'n1' element is written as T(n1).
Time taken to solve problem with 'n2' element is written as T(n2).

Now number of elements in level 1 is n1=n

(Time taken to solve problem on first level)=(Time taken to solve 1st 
node of level 2)+(Time taken to solve 2nd node of level 2)+(Time taken 
to solve last node of level 2) + (It also takes time to combine these 
three nodes given in question i.e.  theta(number of total elements(n))

T(n)=T(n/5)+T(n/5)+T(n/5)+theta(n)
=>T(n)=3T(n/5)+theta(n)
```